Manhwa where the MC laid a trap against an enemy squad
I think this was a martial arts / murim manhwa but I'm not 100% sure.
What I remember is MC laid out a trap against the spy squad of the bad guys. I'm pretty sure that squad leader was a woman. The MC led them near the mountains acting as a bait and made the mountains collapse, burying the whole squad under. The squad leader somewhat survived but I think she lost an arm and she still died to the MC after meeting him again.
